# What's the best way to modify a variable using a function, but inside of another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

The main problem I'm running into (specific to Python, don't mark as duplicate for another language please) is that I don't know how to modify a string variable inside a function, with a nested function, if that makes any sense. This code should do a much better job explaining what I mean.

```
def insideAFunction():
    variableToMod =  "test"

    def modFunc():
        if 1 > 0:
            variableToMod = "TEST"

    print("before: " + variableToMod)
    modFunc()
    print("after: " + variableToMod)


def insideAFunction2():
    variableToMod =  "test"

    def modFunc():
        global variableToMod
        if 1 > 0:
            variableToMod = "TEST"

    print("before: " + variableToMod)
    modFunc()
    print("after: " + variableToMod)

insideAFunction()
insideAFunction2()
```

**Output:**

```
before: test
after: test
before: test
after: test
```

The desired output would be:

```
after: TEST
```

I know I can get it to work by just defining `variableToMod` outside the insideAFunction() and make the global call like in insideAFunction2(), but I want to know if it's possible to do it completely inside the function.

Comment: This smells the duplicate!

Comment: strings in python are non mutable ... you need to return something... however in python3 you can use `nonlocal` instead of `global` and you can probably locate your function scoped variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are changing value of variableToMod in modFunc but not returning it.
2. Second print variableToMod statement is still printing but it takes the variableToMod  you declared in line 2

So it will always print the same. You need to return a value from modFunc and assign it to outer variableToMod before printing. This way the result will be

before: test
after: TEST

def insideAFunction2():
    variableToMod =  "test"

```
def modFunc():
    if 1 > 0:
        variableToMod = "TEST"
        return variableToMod


print("before: " + variableToMod)
variableToMod = modFunc()
print("after: " + variableToMod)
```

Comment: I guess I was just thinking that changing the variable should make it so that when you retrieve the value of it later, the value is different. guess not

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Python 3.x (I don't believe this is an issue in Python 2.x), which means you need to use the `nonlocal` keyword in your inner functions.

I'm guessing the version using `global` doesn't work because you've already defined a local variable with the same name, which would shadow any global variable with that name.

**EDIT:**
Actually, Python 2.x does have this same behavior, but it doesn't support the `nonlocal` statement it seems. I guess one solution might be to pass in the local() dictionary and change the entries in that inside your inner function, but I'm not sure that would work. I'd have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use return function works fine on me:

```
def insideAFunction():
    variableToMod =  "test"

    def modFunc():
        if 1>0:
            variableToMod = "TEST"
            return variableToMod

    print("before: " + variableToMod)
    variableToMod = modFunc()
    print("after: " + variableToMod)

insideAFunction()
```

the output is:

```
before: test
after: TEST
```